# Exact sampling from 2D Ising model where coupling is constant?

Tags: st.statistics, mp.mathematical-physics

What progress has been made towards sampling from the 2D lattice Ising model with the following Hamiltonian:

$H=-J\sum_{\langle i,j \rangle}S_iS_j - \sum_i b_iS_i$

Where the first sum runs over all nearest-neighbour positions on a lattice. Especially, my emphasis is on very large lattice sizes where Markov-chain Monte Carlo methods become unwieldy.

Comment: The title of the question is confusing. Is your question about sampling algorithms or about an Onsager-like exact evaluation of the partition function? There's some detail about the latter on the Wikipedia page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ising_model#Onsager.27s_exact_solution

Comment: Onsager's solution is for when the external field is zero and thus does not apply in this case.

My emphasis is on sampling algorithms. An exact partition function calculation is a very difficult problem for this case.

Comment: How about coupling from the past? It should work pretty well ...


Answer (score 2):

The entropic sampling technique can efficiently sample quite large lattices, several thousands spins. It has been applied to your Hamiltonian, in a uniform magnetic field ($b_i$ independent of $i$), in several works:

[Systematic enumeration of configuration classes for entropic sampling of Ising models](http://arxiv.org/abs/1112.1387),
Bruno Jeferson Lourenço, Ronald Dickman

[Complete high-precision entropic sampling](http://arxiv.org/abs/1107.2951), 
Ronald Dickman, A. G. Cunha-Netto

[Entropic sampling dynamics of the globally-coupled kinetic Ising model,](http://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0503047)
Beom Jun Kim, M.Y. Choi

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the reply. Has there been any progress to solve the Hamiltonian I gave?